The meaning of invariance group by Alain Connes
I read an article about questions asked to Alain Connes in the book Mathématiques, un
dépaysement soudain, pp.6-7.
Original text
Ce que Galois a compris, d’une certaine manière, et c’est un peu le point
de départ des mathématiques vraiment modernes, c’est qu’en fait, il faut
être capable d’aller au-delà des calculs. C’est-à-dire ne pas faire les calculs,
mais en pensée les faire ! Et comprendre quelle sera leur nature, comprendre
quelles seront les difficultés qui vont se présenter, etc., mais sans vraiment effectuer concrètement les calculs, comprendre de quelle forme sera le résultat.
Quelle symétrie aura le résultat. Et donc, dépasser cette espèce de gangue
dans laquelle on s’engluerait facilement si l’on ne levait pas le nez du guidon.
Il faut essayer d’en sortir par le haut, de réfléchir au niveau des symétries, etc.

“Sauter à pieds joints sur ces calculs ; grouper les opérations, les classer
suivant leurs difficultés et non suivant leurs formes ; telle est selon moi, la
mission.”- Evariste Galois

Alors que ses prédécesseurs recherchaient des fonctions symétriques des
racines d’une équation, Galois, lui, commence par briser la symétrie, pour
y voir clair... Son point de départ est le choix arbitraire d’une fonction des
racines qui n’admet aucune symétrie. La merveille est que le groupe d’invariance qu’il déduit du passage de cette fonction aux racines est en fait
indépendant du choix arbitraire initial.
Translation into English
What Galois understood, in a way, and this is a bit of the starting point of truly modern mathematics, is that in fact, you have to be able to go beyond calculations. That is to say, not do the calculations, but do them in thought! And understand what their nature will be, understand what the difficulties that will arise will be, etc., but without really concretely carrying out the calculations, understand what form the result will be. What symmetry the result will have. And therefore, go beyond this kind of gangue in which we would easily get stuck if we did not lift our noses from the handlebars. We must try to get out of it at the top, to think at the level of symmetries, etc.

“Jump into these calculations with both feet; group the operations, classify them according to their difficulties and not according to their forms; This is, in my opinion, the mission.”- Evariste Galois

While his predecessors were looking for symmetric functions of the roots of an equation, Galois begins by breaking the symmetry, to see clearly... His starting point is the arbitrary choice of a function of the roots that does not admit any symmetry. The wonder is that the invariance group that he deduces from the passage of this function to the roots is in fact independent of the initial arbitrary choice.
(I don't know French very well, so I used Google Translate to write in English. Please understand if the translation isn't smooth.)
I'm curious about what the invariance group is here. I think that if there is a cubic equation $x^3+px+q=0$, and the three solutions here are $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, then using $\omega$ from equation $x^3=1$, we get equation $$\alpha+\omega\beta+\omega^2\gamma, \alpha+\omega^2\beta+\omega\gamma$$ and here, the three solutions $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ that we mentioned earlier are substituted,

$\phi_1: \alpha \to \alpha, \beta \to \beta, \gamma \to \gamma$
$\phi_2: \alpha \to \beta, \beta \to \gamma, \gamma \to \alpha$
$\phi_3: \alpha \to \gamma, \beta \to \alpha, \gamma \to \beta$
$\phi_4: \alpha \to \beta, \beta \to \alpha, \gamma \to \gamma$
$\phi_5: \alpha \to \alpha, \beta \to \gamma, \gamma \to \beta$
$\phi_6: \alpha \to \gamma, \beta \to \beta, \gamma \to \alpha$

so is this the invariance group we're talking about here? Because $\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3, \phi_4, \phi_5,$ and $\phi_6$ can form a group. I'm curious about Alain Connes's thoughts on the term invariance group, and whether my guess for an example of an invariance group is correct.
